# send json as inline using discord.py

Tags: javascript, python-3.x, discord.py

I developed my own discord bot in python and I faced the current problem of how to display json embed message using the command.
I had no experience with js, and in order to create an embed I used https://discord.club/ as it is based on a graphical interface.
And I can't find a way to embed json in discord.py

here is the json file itself

```js
{
  "username": "",
  "avatar_url": "",
  "content": "@here",
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "__Installation and Start-Up__",
      "color": 16514816,
      "description": "1. Install [vcredist](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)\n2. Turn your antivirus on and add `Disturbed.exe` and the folder it's in to your antivirus or Windows Defender exceptions.\n3. Make sure background programs such as RAM cleaners (MSI Afterburner & CCleaner) don't interfere with the injection process.\n4. Make sure your GTA V is on the latest version.\n5. Run the game and start the injector. Wait for the game to fully load offline/online, then inject.",
      "timestamp": "",
      "url": "",
      "author": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "image": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "footer": {
        "text": "",
        "icon_url": ""
      },
      "fields": []
    }
  ],
  "components": []
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [`Embed.from_dict`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Embed.from_dict) classmethod

```py
embed_dict = {
  "username": "",
  "avatar_url": "",
  "content": "@here",
  "embeds": [
    {
      "title": "__Installation and Start-Up__",
      "color": 16514816,
      "description": "1. Install [vcredist](https://aka.ms/vs/16/release/vc_redist.x64.exe)\n2. Turn your antivirus on and add `Disturbed.exe` and the folder it's in to your antivirus or Windows Defender exceptions.\n3. Make sure background programs such as RAM cleaners (MSI Afterburner & CCleaner) don't interfere with the injection process.\n4. Make sure your GTA V is on the latest version.\n5. Run the game and start the injector. Wait for the game to fully load offline/online, then inject.",
      "timestamp": "",
      "url": "",
      "author": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "image": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "thumbnail": {
        "url": ""
      },
      "footer": {
        "text": "",
        "icon_url": ""
      },
      "fields": []
    }
  ],
  "components": []
}

embed = discord.Embed.from_dict(embed_dict['embeds'][0])
await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Keep in mind that you can only send *one* embed at a time with a bot

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at [`discord.Embed.from_dict(data)`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?highlight=embed#discord.Embed.from_dict) in the Docs.